# Vue2 @click on element outside of "el"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, click

I have a question to Vue2 and no possibility to test it to see the right answer, because I only have Vue3 working here. Maybe someone of you can help me with this question?

What happens if you use @click=“alert” on an element that is not within the element that you specified for “el” on the Vue instance?

a) The HTML page is not displayed due to an error

b) @click is still interpreted by the browser as a click handler and an alert () box is displayed when you click.

c) “el” is extended by the corresponding selector

d) The code is not processed and a click does not trigger

So for example:

```
    <div id="app">
    <button class="add" @click="click">Press</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="otherapp">
    <button class="add" @click="click">Press</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var app = new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
    
    methods: {
    click()
     {
     alert("click triggered")
    };


)}
```

So what would happen if I click the button with the id "otherapp" which isn´t mentioned in the "el" script?

Comment: please share the whole code

Comment: You should be able to create a fiddle with the right Vue environment and test it there.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens of course, as Vue is only initialised on the #app div:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button class="add" @click="click">Press works</button>
</div>
    
<div id="otherapp">
    <button class="add" @click="click">Press nothing happens</button>
</div>
<script>
var app = new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
      click()
       {
       alert("click triggered")
      }
    }
})
</script>
```